# Deleting item from list cause range error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this document :

```
for (var i = 0; i < ligneDocuments.length; i++) {
  if (ligneDocuments[i]['id_doc'] == widget.ligneDocumentId) {
    setState(() {
      TextEditingController idController = new TextEditingController();
      widget.controllers.add(idController);
      idController.text = ligneDocuments[i]['id'].toString();
      TextEditingController refController = new TextEditingController();
      widget.controllers.add(refController);
      refController.text = ligneDocuments[i]['refProd'].toString();
      TextEditingController nomController = new TextEditingController();
      widget.controllers.add(nomController);
      nomController.text = ligneDocuments[i]['nomProd'].toString();
      TextEditingController qteController = new TextEditingController();
      widget.controllers.add(qteController);
      qteController.text = ligneDocuments[i]['qteProd'].toString();
      TextEditingController prixController = new TextEditingController();
      widget.controllers.add(prixController);
      prixController.text = ligneDocuments[i]['prixProd'].toString();
      TextEditingController totalProdController =
          new TextEditingController();
      totalProdController.text = (double.parse(prixController.text) *
              double.parse(qteController.text))
          .toString();
        print(kk);
        kk++;
        print(kk);
      _cardList.add(InputRefNomProduit(
        index:kk,
        totalDoc: totalDoc,
        totalDocument: totalDocument,
        total: total,
        controllers: widget.controllers,
        label: 'Référence',
        label2: 'Nom du produit',
        label3: 'Quantité',
        label4: 'Prix',
        label5: 'Total par Produit',
        fieldController: refController,
        fieldController2: nomController,
        fieldController3: qteController,
        fieldController4: prixController,
        fieldController5: totalProdController,
        delete: (index){
          print(index);
          setState(() {
            _cardList.removeAt(index);
           
          });
        },
      ));
    });
  }
```

This is how I'm printing my `_cardList` :

```
        SizedBox(
                                    height: 450,
                                    width: 1200,
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: _cardList.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return Padding(padding: 
             EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),child: _cardList[index],);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),



class _InputRefNomProduitState extends State<InputRefNomProduit> {
  bool hasFocus = false;
  String nomProduit;
  String selectedProduit;
  int produitId;
  List produits = [];
  List<String> refProduits = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.fetchProduits();
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  "${widget.label}",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // more Expanded inputs 
            
            
            IconButton(onPressed: (){
              widget.delete(widget.index);
            }, icon: Icon(Icons.close)),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

at the top , I'm trying to check if some inputs are == to what exists in my BD .
Then , print the items with a Icon Button with `remove` function .

I'm facing the problem that when I delete an item , I'm getting different counter for the `_cardList` length , and the index of item that I want to delete.

After deleting 1 item, I'm getting error like this :

```
Another exception was thrown: RangeError: Value not in range: 3.
```

The card list length went from 4 to 3 and the item I'm trying to delete is still index=3.

I tried without the `index[kk]` variable using just `removeAt[index]` , and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

these are one of two options you can try.
1.

```
 _cardList.removeAt(index);    
setState(() {
           
           
          });
```

2. 

```
//outside of loop
     void refresh(){
 setState((){});
}
//then inside loop
_cardList.removeAt(index); 
refresh();
```

The 1. answer is how I solved my issue which is dervied from this stackoverflow post.
[Flutter , index out of range when i try to delete an item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011871/flutter-index-out-of-range-when-i-try-to-delete-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: 1 month and I'm still stuck . I will try this , hope it will work. Thank you.